# bad gateway elasticbeanstalk application

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I ran application locally with the properties. It started fine and connected to `RDS` successfully. Also it worked fine in browser when I navigate to `localhost:8080/main`.

Then I build a `jar` using `mvnw package`, put it into ZIP and uploaded in me Elasticbeanstalk application.

In my network configuration I selected all `subnets` and my Elasticbeanstalk application uses the same `VPC` as RDS instance. Also I selected all `rds launch wizard` security groups in instances configuration for it. It seems to start successfully and connected to RDS as my logs contain lines and no exceptions

```
2018-08-03 18:54:21.331  INFO 4085 --- [           main] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Registering beans for JMX exposure on startup
2018-08-03 18:54:21.347  INFO 4085 --- [           main] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Bean with name 'dataSource' has been autodetected for JMX exposure
2018-08-03 18:54:21.363  INFO 4085 --- [           main] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Located MBean 'dataSource': registering with JMX server as MBean [com.zaxxer.hikari:name=dataSource,type=HikariDataSource]
2018-08-03 18:54:21.521  INFO 4085 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (http) with context path ''
2018-08-03 18:54:21.535  INFO 4085 --- [           main] xxxx                                     : Started Application in 27.799 seconds (JVM running for 31.318)
```

But when I try to navigate `http://blablabla.us-east-1.elasticbeanstalk.com/main` I get `BAD GATEWAY` page and the same for `/main` route.

What is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was solved.
It seems EB is using trying to access port `5000`, while by default Spring Boot starts application on port `8080`.

I set property in *application.properties* file

```
server.port=5000
```

Also just in case in set additional `inbound` port in my security group configuration for EC2

```
Custom TCP Rule TCP 5000 0.0.0.0/32
```

Now it works fine.